# on a set of numbers with special property

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $A$ be a set   of positive Real numbers such that

if $a,b \in A$ and $a\neq b$ then $a^b\in A$ or $b^a\in A$.

Now prove that  a finite set $A$ has no more than 4 elements.

For example $A=\{1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{16}\}$ is such a set of 4 elements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If we have such a set $A$, we can freely add $1$, so we can assume that $1\in A$ already, and suppose it has $3$ more elements, $a<b<c$, say.

If $a>1$ (hence all are $>1$), then $c^a$ and $c^b$ are both $>c$, and this way we can produce infinitely many different elements.

If $a<1<b$ then $a^b<a$ and $1<b^a<b$, so this again produces one more element for sure. 
(If $A$ already has more elements, take the least element for $a$ and the least element above $1$ for $b$ to obtain a new element.) 
The case $b<1<c$ leads to the same.

So, if $A$ is finite, all of its elements are $<1$. 
I guess, similar reasoning would work for this case, too. 
Can you take it from here?